# Can I force someone into my bag of holding?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I'm playing an artificer, and I have the [bag of holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding) infusion. I was thinking that if I put a whole person in a bag of holding against his or her will, that would be basically an instakill, right?

My DM said that in my infusioned bag of holding nothing living can enter, and if it does, it instantly dies. How do I do that? Just a regular melee attack roll? Do I make an opposed strength check? What if we are just talking and I randomly do that, does that count as a surprise round so I can do it before rolling for initiative?

Bags of holding are 2 feet wide, does a dwarf fit in there? (I want to kill a really bad dwarf mafia boss.)

Comment: Related: [Can I push an enemy into a bag of holding?](/questions/164855/), [Can a Bag of Holding ever be habitable?](/questions/164506), [Can I put something wider than 2 feet into a Bag of Holding (such as a humanoid)?](/questions/79358), [How does attacking during a conversation affect initiative?](/questions/154283)

Comment: I will suggest that you discuss with the DM what the time limit on enough air to breath is in the standard bag of holding (in the DMG)  ... we have a  few Q&A on this site that discuss that little detail.